# Custom options for products in Magento

Tags: php, magento

1. I have used the following code to Get product custom options in list.phtml
2. This code it worked and displayed the product attribute set. 
   **But**
3. It is not displaying multiple Custom options i have created for the product and also fetches only 2 values in the Attribute set.

**To make it more clear.**

See i have Drop-down, Input field, Radio-button with values for a product. but through the below code it shows only one drop-down with 2 value options.

**There is one more thing i would like to know**

How to send the Product, price, Qty and Custom option Selected to cart when **add-to-cart button clicked**.

Please Guide me. Thank you

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$attVal = $_product->getOptions();
$optStr = "";

// loop through the options
foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal) {
    $optStr .= "<br/>";
    $optStr .= $optionVal->getTitle().": "; 
    $optStr .= "<select style='display:block; clear:both;' name='options[".$optionVal->getId()."]'>"; 
    foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
        $optStr .= "<option value='".$valuesVal->getId()."'>".$valuesVal->getTitle()."</option>";
    }
    $optStr .= "</select>";
}
```